# Need math explaining calculation of number of binary tree topologies given n nodes

Tags: algorithms, permutations

Grinding through leetcode, I came across the question of the number of binary tree topologies for n nodes.

When looking up the best solutions, I saw the same line of code in each solution:

```
numberOfTrees += numberOfLeftTrees * numberOfRightTrees;
```

Why is the number of left and right trees multiplied together?

Whole solution is given here for context:

````
    public int NumberOfBinaryTreeTopologies(int n, Dictionary<int, int> memo)
    {
        if(memo.TryGetValue(n, out int value))
            return value;

        int numberOfTrees = 0;

        for(int leftTreeSize = 0; leftTreeSize < n; leftTreeSize++)
        {
            int rightTreeSize = n - 1 - leftTreeSize;
            int numberOfLeftTrees = NumberOfBinaryTreeTopologies(leftTreeSize, memo);
            int numberOfRightTrees = NumberOfBinaryTreeTopologies(rightTreeSize, memo);
            numberOfTrees += numberOfLeftTrees * numberOfRightTrees;
            // why is this multiplied? It is not really explained.
        }

        memo.Add(n, numberOfTrees);
        return numberOfTrees;
    }
```
````

Comment: Why are they multiplied? Say you want to have a pizza. You have 3 choices for the base and 5 for the toppings. How many different pizzas can you choose from?

Comment: @RinkeshP: that makes sense. So it is the combination of possible subtrees for right and left?